# Rude Moderators

Tags: discussion

I've been using Stack Exchange for many years now, mainly the technology boards relating to programming since probably 2009/2010, and over the years I have found it a valuable resource.

Long story short, I recently lost my [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) device and lost access to a lot of my online accounts. I had a good SO account previously with lots of rep which was linked to a Facebook account and email I can no longer access.

Since using SO and some of the other tech boards under my new account with virtually no rep, I have found detailed questions go unanswered and moderators quickly downvote questions and answers. They are dismissive and outright rude.

I have started flagging rude responses and calling them out on it and have actually got one half decent apology from a moderator blaming it on an automated response.

But then the more I look the more I see it everywhere moderators frankly being fallacies to users. I don't want to generalize the wider Stack Exchange community as I only really use it for the tech boards. Is this a developer thing? I've see many egotistical developers in professional workplaces who have some kind of superiority complex to those they perceive more junior to themselves. Have all these people congregated as the moderator team on these tech boards? Or is it more to do with the perception that because I'm using an account with little rep therefore I am a "noob" and stupid?

I'm of the understanding that these people volunteer their time to moderating the boards rather than being paid staff. That said, I would assume they do this because they enjoy helping people rather than some status symbol where they are better than other people and therefore they have the right to be rude to other members. It seems almost that the people being rude are doing this as a chore and are lashing out.

Once over I quite enjoyed coming on these boards to ask questions, broaden my knowledge, converse with other people in my field and where I can give back and answer questions. But now it has become a last resort where I dread posting wondering, what random comment am I going to get back this time.

I'm not sure this question has a resolution, but this is something that has pent-up up over several months.

Comment: When you say moderators, you seem to mean other, high rep users with access to community moderation tools like voting, flagging, closing and deleting posts - is that the case? These are just *normal* users like yourself (only with more reputation and therefore privileges).

Comment: From the evidence you present, it seems because your a count is new, a lot of your posts are being automatically put in review queues, and when people review them the system automatically posts comments on them noting how they can be improved. You have interpreted these automated comments as individuals targeting you specifically with abusive language. That's not what is happening. Also please note that there is a difference between a moderator and a high-rep user. Likely you are seeing review comments from high-rep users (i.e. everyday people), not mods, who always have a ♦️ after their name.

Comment: **"I had a good SO account previously with lots of rep"** - Although it is quite unimportant, but was it really that many reputation points? Your constant misuse of the word "mods" makes me wonder if you really are as familiar with the structure of Stack Exchange sites as you say you are. **"I have started flagging rude responses and calling them out on it and have actually got one half assed apology from a mod blaming it on an automated response. "** - which of the automatic responses do sound rude? Do you have examples, so they can be changed?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just over-reacting here? Looking through your activity on this account, almost none of your posts are downvoted and very few have any comments under them. You can't take a couple of situations and exaggerate it into "this happens to me all the time." You also can't [point out comments as rude](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169342/should-this-go-in-a-repository#comment321676_169342) just because they're trying to point out that your question isn't answerable in its current form. Disagree != rude.

Comment: I think if you don't provide any examples, we can't' effectively discuss anything. It shouldn't be really hard to come up with examples if high-rep users are indeed that commonly being rude to users in any SE site. You find something rude, but if you don't show proof, we can never know if it really happened.

Comment: "I had a good SO account previously with lots of rep which was linked to a facebook account and email I can no longer access." You can ask SE to merge your accounts. I'm sure they will be able to help. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts)

Answer (score 13):

> I have found detailed questions go unanswered, mods quickly down vote questions and answers, they are dismissive and outrightly rude.

Speaking from someone who used to think this constantly (me) to someone else, let me tell you something. One, mods = people who haves lots of rep and thus have moderation privileges. Two, if new users even bothered (they rarely do) to read the Help Center and Tour for their respective site, then the posts posted would have better quality and match with the requirements.

Downvotes are commonly used when the question is poorly formed (no basis to go back on, little information presented about the problem, no apparent attempts to solve the problem, etc). I really don't know what to say anymore. With all of these rant-type posts (in honesty), there usually is one common answer: read the Help Center and Tour!

> have actually got one half assed apology from a mod blaming it on an automated response.

There are automated responses such as the system produces when someone casts a close vote for being a duplicate. You might want to check what this automated response is and learn more about it (you can ask in chat nicely).

> Or is it more to do with the perception that because i'm using an account with little rep therefore Im a "noob" and stupid?

No, less rep doesn't really mean anything much. *Compared* to someone with more rep (like at least a (or few) hundred not like 50), we can trust the other guy more but that doesn't mean you're a noob or stupid or that you should GTFO. Everyone starts out at 1 rep, including the high rep people like Jon Skeet. I started with 1 and with some knowledge about how the site work and good, at-least-par-quality posts, I'm now at 15.7k rep!

> I've see many egotistical developers in professional workplaces who have some kind of superiority complex to those they perceive more junior to themselves, have all these people congregated as the mod team on these tech boards?

If the lead developer(s) for Microsoft, Apple, etc. made their debut on Stack Overflow (or some other site) but rarely did anything (i.e answering and asking), their rep would not be that high. What do I mean by this? Rep is only an assumption (a very rough one) of how trustworthy you are.

> Im on the understanding that these people volunteer their time to moderating the boards rather than being paid staff, that said I would assume they do this because they enjoy helping people rather than some status symbol where they are better than other people therefore they have the right to be rude to other members.

Who gets paid? Sure, the actual workers of SE get paid but in other ways. Some of the moderators here *are paid staff for Stack Exchange Inc.* and they enjoy banning the heck out of others (or even removing mod status from elected moderators) that try to abuse people because they have more rep/have a mod status.

If you read the Help Center, you would realize two things. One, there is a Be Nice policy, which is technically applicable to all online sites, but is definitely enforced here for obvious reasons. Two, the enforcement comes with the flags, which have several reasons not limited to rudeness/abusiveness. Wanna be rude? Then you enjoy your warning and in the future, suspension and I really hope it doesn't get to the point of account deletion.

> It seems almost that the people being rude are doing this as a chore and are lashing out.

There is a very clear understanding that you *volunteer* to provide information (answers or comments) or questions (literally questions).

> But now it has become a last resort where I dread posting wondering, what shi**y comment am I going to get back this time.

To end this answer, I am going to provide you with one last piece of information that help got me to where I am now and (I can't speak for others though) probably everyone else who has a decent chunk of rep: ***Read the Tour if you're new to get a quick glance on how the site works at first. Then, read the Help Center thoroughly to get a much more firmer grasp on how the site works.***

I'm also going to add this (my) answer from Meta Stack Overflow since it should help a bit more and it covers some topics not seen here (though more applicable to asking but most new users ask first): [How can I improve my own experience of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299823/4052384)

Comment: **Not** reading the site rules and jumping to the conclusion the site sucks is sooo common it hurts...